# RecyclerView checkbox deselect all?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-checkbox

I'm wondering how I'd be able to use a button in another class to deselect all checkboxes in my 3 recyclerviews(Tablayout, one recyclerview per tab). I have saved the checked value in shared pref as shown here:

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

Context mContext;
ArrayList<Workout> workout;
SharedPreferences prefs;
int firstSecondOrThird;
int colorResId = R.color.defaultcard;

public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Workout> workout, int thePosition) {
    mContext = context;
    this.workout = workout;
    this.firstSecondOrThird = thePosition;
}
// INITIALIZE HOLDER
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.workout_item, null);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);

    return holder;
}

//BIND DATA TO VIEWS
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.exercise.setText(workout.get(position).getExercise());
    holder.percent.setText(workout.get(position).getPercent());
    holder.reps.setText(workout.get(position).getReps());
    holder.weight.setText(workout.get(position).getWeight());
    holder.check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

    final Workout isCheck = workout.get(position);

    prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("checkState", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       holder.check1.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean(firstSecondOrThird+"checkState"+position, false));
    isCheck.setCheck1(prefs.getBoolean(firstSecondOrThird+"checkState"+position, false));
holder.check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            prefs.edit().putBoolean(firstSecondOrThird+"checkState"+position, isChecked).apply();
        }
    });

}
```

And here is where I try to clear shared pref, which I thought would also clear all checkmarks:

```
mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            prefs.edit().clear();
            prefs.edit().apply();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checkboxes Cleared.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}
```

Unfortunately, after clicking the button, all checkboxes that were previously selected are still selected. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I tried to add an if statement to see if that would work, but now it doesn't load the saved checkmarks are all, even when the button isn't clicked... lol

```
prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("checkState", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String restoredCheck = prefs.getString("checkState", null);
    if (restoredCheck != null) {
        holder.check1.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean(firstSecondOrThird+"checkState"+position, false));
    } else holder.check1.setChecked(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to alter the List inside the adapter, then, call `((MyRecyclerAdapter) mMyListView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();`

For experience, some times depending on what change are made, the adapter do not update with this, in this cases, i create a new adapter with the new list of data, and set to the ListView, after, you may need to call the notifyDataSetChanged() anyway

Edit:

Well, inside your adapter you use a `List', the state change must be done in that List, and after that you notify the adapter that the data was changed.

So you need a method to get the ArrayList and do something like:

```
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ArrayList<Workout> list = ((MyRecyclerAdapter) MyListView.getAdapter()).getList();

    for(Workout workout : list){
workout.setCheck(true);

}

((MyRecyclerAdapter) MyListView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
    }
```

I'm not able to test right now, but i think it's some like that, like i said, if this don't work, create another adapter with the new data and set him to the ListView.

Ps. I considered you correctly check if the object isChecked and change the checkbox in the ViewHoler

Comment: This kind of confuses me.. I think there must be a simpler way? I edited my question to try a new possibility

Comment: Seems like the simplest solution to me: bind a click listener to the 'Select/Deselect All' button, loop through the adapter's items while setting them as checked/unchecked, and notify the adapter to have the views updated.